# Updateable view of local table and linked server table - data has changed

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

i need to combine two tables on a local and a linked server in a updateable view on my local sql-server, which i link to an MS Access Frontend.
Accessing this view in Access works, and updates to existing rows on the local table works to. But i can not add new rows to this local table as the foreign key [ProjektNr] is not set automatically. Sadly it is not possible to add a foreign key contraint between local and linked server, so i need an alternative. I already read about replicating/tringgering the foreign table in a local table, but this is not what i want. The two tables have a 1:1 relation. If a want to attach [Notizen] to a known Project, i need a new row in [tblProjekt] with matching [ProjektNr], but this row is not generated by updating the view. I get:

> data has changed since the results pane was last retrieved

even directly in SSMS.

my local table where i can attach further projectinformation to existing projects: (SQL-Server 2014)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblProjekt](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjektNr] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Notizen] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblProjekt] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

my linked server table which i don´t want to touch: (SQL-Server 2008R2)

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Projekt](
    [MandantNr] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ProjektNr] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KundenNr] [int] NULL,
    [ProjektName] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Abgeschlossen] [bit] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Projekt] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [MandantNr] ASC,
        [ProjektNr] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Projekt]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Projekt_Mandanten] FOREIGN KEY([MandantNr])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Mandanten] ([MandantNr])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Projekt] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Projekt_Mandanten]
    GO
```

my local combining view:

```
SELECT Projekt_1.ProjektNr, Projekt_1.KundenNr, Projekt_1.ProjektName, 
    CASE WHEN (tblProjekt.ProjektNr IS NULL) THEN '0' ELSE '-1' END AS Übernommen, dbo.tblProjekt.ID, dbo.tblProjekt.ProjektNr AS GProjektNr, dbo.tblProjekt.Notizen, dbo.tblProjekt.TimeStamp, Projekt_1.Abgeschlossen, Projekt_1.MandantNr
        FROM LINKEDSERVER.Catalog.dbo.Projekt AS Projekt_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblProjekt ON Projekt_1.ProjektNr = dbo.tblProjekt.ProjektNr
        WHERE (Projekt_1.Abgeschlossen = 0) AND (Projekt_1.MandantNr = 1)
```

Problem solved:
Sadly SQL-Server seems not to be able to solve this simple task.
I linked the to tables in Access, wrote the same query and it worked instantly.

Comment: This sounds like a truly horrible design. You have data for a single entity spread across two different database servers. What a complete nightmare. Why can't you put all of your Projekt data on a single server?

Comment: The linked server belongs to a third party software, which i don´t want to compromise. I only need it to grab the ProjektNr (and read other data) and do my own stuff in this FrontEnd.

Comment: OK so what is the issue? I don't understand what you are having a problem with. Also, why are you using the timestamp datatype here? And you really should avoid using reserved words like a datatype as a column name.

Comment: I renamed the timestamp columnname. The timestamp should help MS Access to check, if someone has altered data... I selected the linked table into a local table, added the foreign key and rebuild the combining view. But same Error: data has changed since the results pane was last retrieved. The Problem seems to have nothing to do with the linked server.

Comment: But what is the issue? What is it that you are trying to do that you can't get working?